# How Can I Solve Grouped List Corner Radius Issue?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm using Grouped List style for listing events. I have an interesting issue about it. I added NavigationLink for going to the event details but when I tap to the back button on the event page, the event list item's corner radius being like zero. If you look at the screenshots below you can understand what I mean :)

Before going to the detail page:

[image]

After:

[image]

And My Code:

```
List {
    ForEach(self.viewModel.data, id: \.id) { event in
        Section(header:
            HStack {
                Text("\(event.date.dateValue().eventTime())")
            }
        ) {
            NavigationLink(destination: EventDetail(data: .constant(event))) {
                HStack {
                    Text(event.title)
                }
                Spacer()
                ZStack {
                    Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                    Text("\(event.invited.count)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}.listStyle(GroupedListStyle()).environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the horizontal size class environment?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez it does not look like what I want if I remove it. When I remove it, there are no horizontal paddings and it's flat :)

Comment: I’d recommend you file feedback with Apple as this is unexpected behaviour. Also try to remove the `.listStyle` view modifier... in your case `Sections` applied to a default `List` should provide the same function and appearance.

Comment: You're seeing unexpected behaviour because you're "forcing" a regular horizontal size class on a compact width device. The answer you found is a better solution, what you were doing in your question is a hack, so I'm not surprised you were seeing funky behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not fix this issue, I think it's a bug of apple. I made similar view without the grouped list :) If someone interest I added these styles to HStack that inside of NavigationLink

```
.padding().background(Color(UIColor.systemGray6)).cornerRadius(12)
```